# Extracting data from complex file structure

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a txt file that is a dump from a database, that contains one entry per line. The structure is like this:

```
1500
29/03/2010 
18
02
09
47
17
45
28.248
0
0.01
130
12.721
7908
298,809
YES
3.046.550,39
6.500.000,00
17,444,222


1501
30/03/2010
27
54
28
50
22
03
37.223
0
0.00
97
22,466
7379
421.90
NO
20,262,429
25,000,000.01
17,995,281.33


... the third record starts here
```

The database contains 21 fields. The previous lines shows the dump of two records of that database. The blank lines represent blank fields on the database.

The first field (F0) is the number you see 1500, 1501...

The second field (F1) is a date in the format day, month, year.

Fields F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7 are six integer numbers.

What I need is to extract F0, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7 from this file creating one line for each one.

Given the two records above, the final file would be

```
1500,18,02,09,47,17,45
1501,27,54,28,50,22,03
```

I know how to do that using a bash script that will be miles long and interact over each line, etc. But I also know that unix is a bag of tricks, specially the `sed` command and that this probably can be done with a simple line. I love to learn new stuff, so I ask you guys that are gods in Unix, how do I do that.

I am on OSX Mavericks. Thanks.

Comment: Will the last field always be empty, i.e. will there always be an empty line between records? If not, then @terdon's code will not work correctly. It depends on the empty line (paragraph mode reading).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$ perl -000ne '@f=split(/\n/); print join(",",@f[0,2..7]) , "\n"' file.txt  
1500,18,02,09,47,17,45
1501,27,54,28,50,22,03
```

#### Explanation:

- `-000` : activates "paragraph mode", it sets `perl`'s field delimiter to `\n\n`, consecutive newlines. This means that it will treat each of your records as a single line.
- `@f=split(/\n/);` : split the current line (the record) on newlines and save as the array `@f`. This array now contains each field from your record. This means that the array slice `@f[0,2..8]` will contain fields 0 and 2 through 8.
- `print join ",",@f[0,2..8] , "\n"'` : this will join the array slice with commas, and print the resulting string followed by a newline.

Comment: nice solution :)

Comment: almost there. I have changed your code to include just the fields I have asked: I have changed the line `@f[0..8]` to `@f[0,2,3,4,5,6,7]` but my problem is that a comma is included at the end of each line...

Comment: @DigitalRobot ouch. Thanks for the edit, I had indeed misread the question. I also had a silly mistake which was adding the commas. Try the updated version.

Comment: SIMPLY PERFECT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You are a genius and awesome!!!! Can't up vote you enough! Care to explain why adding a parenthesis there solved the problem?

Comment: @Gnouc thanks for the edit, that's what I'd used initially and forgot to edit the OP's suggestion.

Comment: @DigitalRobot because the `join` was getting confused. The original `print join ",",@f[0..8] , "\n"` was interpreted as "print (`@f[0..8]` and `\n`) joined by ",". By adding the parenthesis I separated the `join()` call from the print, and clarified that I meant "print join(",",@f[0,2..7]) and _then_ print a `\n`".

Answer (score 5):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    fields[1]
    fields[3]
    fields[4]
    fields[5]
    fields[6]
    fields[7]
    last_field=8
  }
  ( NR%21 in fields ) { printf($0",") }
  NR%21==last_field' in_file.txt
```

Or better yet:

```
awk '
  NR%21 ~ /^(1|3|4|5|6|7)$/ { printf($0",") }
  NR%21==8' in_file.txt
```

GNU `sed` has a nice extension to match the nth line after a given one which is useful here. It won't work on OSX, but for the fun of it:

```
sed -n '
  1~21 { h }
  3~21,7~21 { H }
  8~21 { H; g; s/\n/,/gp }' in_file
```

Comment: @DigitalRobot, thanks. Took me a few tries, but I got there in the end.

Comment: @awk_FTW, yeah I made the same mistake at first, but it is the indices that matter for `in` not the values. If you can find a way to shorten it though, feel free.

Answer (score 0):

If your data always have some number of missing fields (*i.e.* 2 or more hard returns between records), you could simply:

```
$ awk -v RS="\\n{2,}" -F"\\n" -v OFS="," '{print $1, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8}' file.txt
1500,18,02,09,47,17,45
1501,27,54,28,50,22,03
```